# How to Install or enable PHP-FTP support on Linux Apache server?

Tags: php, tomcat, ftp, rhel

In my PHP code i am using the below function

```
ftp_connect()
```

but it throws an error, FTP is not enabled for PHP.

can any one tell me how to enable/install FTP in RHEL, Apache2.2 server,PHP Version is 5.3.3.

This server is **Production** now my concern is if i reinstall PHP is it going to disturb my current environment?

Comment: [FTP Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php): You have to recompile it.

Comment: <?php
     phpinfo();
     ?>
Look for "ftp support", it should be marked "enabled".

Comment: Thank you. While re-installing php is it disturb my current environment? @RichardReiber

Comment: @naveen: If you just recompile it, it would not.

Comment: if you don't mine can you check with the below code & let me know any thing is missing
1) go to php folder
2) ./configure --php-ftp
3) make
4) make install
@RichardReiber

Comment: Make a file with `phpinfo();`, there you should have the `Configure Command`. Use it and add --php-ftp.

Comment: Thank you so much. while recompile it won't effect the php.ini ? if you don't mine can you give the exact steps because i don't have experience in PROD server for installation so if something goes wrong it will effect for me. @RichardReiber